# How to create the predict model for Multiple input on keras using LSTM

Tags: time-series, keras, lstm, predict

[image]

When there is only one input, I can use lstm to complete the forecast. When the following two cases, I will be confused, do not know how to build a neural network:
The data format is shown in the picture。

- The first case:
  Use a, b, c, d to predict d (t + 1)
- The second case:
  d= f (a, b, c) f is an unknown nonlinear function, using a, b, c, d to predict d (t + 1)

Answer (score 0):

Simply concatenate the inputs in an array with the following dimensions:

```
(number_of_samples, timesteps, number_of_features)
```

Where `number_of_features` in your case is 4 as you have a,b,c,d. Your `input_shape` of the first layer will be `(timesteps, number_of_features)`.